# Especificar caminhos customizados de View's no ASP NET Core 2.0 MVC 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, asp.net, mvc

Estou tendo um grande problema em especificar o caminho que eu desejo que o controller busque a view relativa a ele.

Estou usando mais de um subpasta dentro de um area:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu desejo que o controller possa navegar para pastas como "Navegacao" e "Servicos" (Views/Servicos/(nome da view).

Qual seria a melhor forma para faze-lo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cada pasta da sua View, geralmente é referente a um de seus controller, portanto se você deseja acionar uma outra view a partir de outro controller, ou seja, da mesma pasta, você so precisa usar o seguinte:

```
return RedirectToAction("Action", "Controller")
```

Caso você deseja acionar uma view do mesmo controller, ou seja, da mesma pasta, você pode fazer assim:

```
return RedirectToAction("Action")
```

ou

```
return View("Action")
```

Tudo depende do que você quer/precisa fazer...

Para que fique simples pra você, pense uma `Action` é uma `View`

Comment: Funcionou obrigado :D